# Score "undefined" javascript

Tags: javascript, console

In [this Odin course](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-rock-paper-scissors#project-solution) there is a task to make a "Rock, paper, scissors" game. When trying to add a scorecounter, the score comes back as "undefined", even though the score for both the player and computer is tracked correctly through the program. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Code:

```
let Choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;


function getComputerChoice() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Choices.length);

    return Choices[random];
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return "Draw!";
    }
    else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
        computerScore++;
        return ("Computer Wins!");
    }
    else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        playerScore++;
        return ("You Win!");
    }
    else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
        playerScore++;
        return ("You Win!");
    }
    else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        computerScore++;
        return ("Computer Wins!");
    }
    else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
        computerScore++;
        return ("Computer Wins!");
    }
    else {
        return ("You Win!");
    }
}

function playGame(playerScore, computerScore) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        let computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
        let playerSelection = "Rock";
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
        console.log(`Player: ${playerScore}\nComputer: ${computerScore}`);
    }
}

console.log(playGame());
```

I've checked if the "playerScore" and "computerScore" is tracked correctly, by using "console.log()" prior to the "return statements" in the "if statement". However when trying to output the code correctly in the "for loop" it just says "undefined".

[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5wjN.png)

Comment: `console.log(playGame());` will output `undefined` of course, is that the issue?

Comment: `function playGame(playerScore, computerScore) {` ... those arguments "mask" the globals - get rid of them, and your code will almost be right .... except for one particular combination where "you win" without getting a point

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, that is the problem. However I just now tried to include write it like this "console.log(playGame(playerScore, computerScore));". And this does not display the updated score values.

Comment: because `function playGame(playerScore, computerScore) { ... those arguments "mask" the globals - get rid of them`

Answer (score 0):

`playerScore` and `computerScore` are defined globally.

By having parameters with the same names in your `playGame` function, you're **hiding** the global ones. And since you're calling the function without passing values for these parameters, they're implicitly `undefined`.

Remove those parameters and your should be fine:

```js
function playGame() {
     // Here ----^
```